# Why am I getting the error "'Starting PHP Built-in Server at localhost' has encountered a problem. Only the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server"?

Tags: php, eclipse-plugin

I have been trying to learn PHP and I've been working in Eclipse PHP perspective to do this. I went through and set up the built in server and I had it running fine, but now it has stopped working when I try to run on server. The error message I get is:  "'Starting PHP Built-in Server at localhost' has encountered a problem. Only the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server". How do I fix this?

Comment: The only thing I have found to do that works without reinstalling eclipse, is to delete the .metadata for the workspace I'm working in, import my project back into the workspace, and set the PHP built-in Server back up. I'm looking for a different solution that doesn't involve removing my current projects and metadata for when this happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (switching from wamp to xamp) and found that deleting the directory org.eclipse.wst.server.core in .metadata/.plugins does trigger the setup routine for the PHP built-in Server.